# SharePoint Customization - Order of CSS

Tags: publishing-site, css, branding

I'm branding a SharePoint 2010 publishing site. I'm deploying a custom master page and CSS style sheet using a Feature. I'm applying CSS as an alternate style sheet using the UI: Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Master Page, but my custom style sheet is not being applied last as I feel it should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/en-US/Themable/Core%20Styles/controls.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/search.css?rev=T%2Bhraxktc1A8EnaG5gGMHQ%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=iIikGkMuXBs8CWzKDAyjsQ%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/Custom.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/en-US/Themable/Core%20Styles/nightandday.css"/>
```

Is this a bug? With SharePoint 2007 it would have been applied last affording me the chance to override the built-in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place [CSSRegistration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.cssregistration.aspx) for your custom css on **first line** and specify [After](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.cssregistration.after.aspx) property to **corev4.css** as shown in example below

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style%20Library/Custom.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/controls.css %>" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/nightandday.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

then it will be rendered as you expected i suppose

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/en-US/Themable/Core%20Styles/controls.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/en-US/Core%20Styles/page-layouts-21.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css?rev=iIikGkMuXBs8CWzKDAyjsQ%3D%3D"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/en-US/Themable/Core%20Styles/nightandday.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/Custom.css"/>
```

[CssLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.csslink.aspx) control responsible for ordering and rendering css files on page depends on several factors:

1. Order of placing CSSRegistration control
2. If parameter After specified
3. If [Alternate Css](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.alternatecssurl.aspx) specified

Comment: irishchieftain let me know please if it doesn't help

Comment: I'm glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a css expert but did you try to play with the after property?

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="/Style Library/customfile2.css" After="customfile1.css" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Seb, I tried that with After="nightandday.css" and it has no effect.